# For loop with list

Tags: python, list, for-loop

**The Code**

```py
def f(x, l=[] ):
    for i in range(x):
        l.append(i*i)
        print(l)

f(2)
f(2, [3,2,1])
f(3)
```

***Result of the program:***

```
[0]
[0, 1]
[3, 2, 1, 0]
[3, 2, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 4]
```

I can't figure out why f(3) prints:

```
[0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 4]
```

instead of

```
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 4]
```

Why does **f(2, [3,2,1])** changes the result of **f(3)**, but **f(2)** does not interfere with **f(2, [3,2,1])**?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument